# What is written on the back of this photo?

Tags: images, data-derivation

The following is written on the backside of an image. The picture is of a very young girl with very curly hair, and the comments are by her father. While I can make out most of the words there are some about which I am unsure. Can anyone provide a reasonable transcription of the comments?

[image: comments about Dolly]

Here's what I can parse:

```
Dolly's hair was
curled for the last
time when this was
taken. her hair is ?newly?
?cur? + she looks every
inch a ?bug?.
                J.O.E
```

**Edit:** Here's the picture:

[image: Dolly]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your original transcription is, [as wzeigler also points out](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2937/442), correct on the issue of "newly cut" rather than "now cut" as in the other answers. The most significant clue is that the author obviously in the habit of leaving long tails on their `y`'s and `g`s. Secondarily the lead in to the vowel lends itself just as well to being an `e` as an `o`, however this point is up for debate. Either word makes sense in context and does not significantly change the meaning of the note.

Combining all the results here, the final rendering runs as follows:

> Dollys hair was
>   curled for the last
>   time when this was
>   taken. her hair is newly
>   cut + she looks every
>   inch a boy.
>   J.O.E

As noted above, it is possible that line #4 was meant to read:

> taken. her hair is now

(Note I have left the capitalization and apostrophe mistakes *sic* the original rather than fixing them as a couple transcriptions have done.)

Comment: While I agree with you about the tail, I'm not sure about the vowel lead-in. For example, "looks" on line five seems to have a similar lead-in.

Comment: The e from other words are closed, however the o are open. I would suggest it is now?

Answer (score 30):

Dolly's hair was
curled for the last
time when this was
taken. her hair is now
cut & she looks every
inch a boy.

Comment: That is both wonderful and hilarious at the same time. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I would say "newly cut," since the ending is similar to "every" and "boy."

Comment: Definitely. The descent of the "y" is the same pattern in all three words.

Answer (score 7):

Dolly's hair was

curled for the last

time when this was

taken. her hair is now

cut & she looks every

inch a boy.

```
      J.O.E
```

Answer (score 4):

Dolly's hair was
curled for the last
time when this was
taken. her hair is very
curly & she looks every
inch a boy.